# How to get text on entry from another page Android - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to get string on `<Entry/>` from another page. In my iOS project works but in my Android project work only when I click on the second page after I click on the first page and for second time when I click on the second page He work from OnApearing() method. I want when for first time I click to display the string on  from another page.

My code on second page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Views
{
    public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        RestServiceForecast _restServiceForecast;

    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        _restServiceForecast = new RestServiceForecast();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        string cityName = Preferences.Get("cityName", "default_value");

        _cityEntry.Text = cityName;

        _ = WeatherForecast();
    }
```

When I put this code in the constructor He not working on android. (In iOS I not have a problem).

```
string cityName = Preferences.Get("cityName", "default_value");

    _cityEntry.Text = cityName;

    _ = WeatherForecast();
```

From the first page I get the string with this code:

```
Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);
```

Comment: Why are you passing data between pages using Preferences?  Using the constructor or a public property or method would be much more straightforward.  This has been demonstrated to you in previous questions.

Comment: Can you give me example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the value via the constructor

in your `About` page

```
private string city;

public AboutPage(string city)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    _restServiceForecast = new RestServiceForecast();

    this.city = city;
}
```

then when you call it from the first page

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage(_cityEntry.Text));
```